# How to check if a python object is a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, types

I have a function that takes an array as input and does some computation on it. The input array may or may not be a numpy ndarray (may be a list, pandas object, etc).

In the function, I convert the input array (regardless of its type) to a numpy ndarray. But this step may be computationally expensive for large arrays, especially if the function is called multiple times in a for loop.

Hence, I want to convert the input array to numpy ndarray ONLY if it is not already a numpy ndarray.

How can I do this?

```py
import numpy as np

def myfunc(array):
    # Check if array is not already numpy ndarray
    # Not correct way, this is where I need help
    if type(array) != 'numpy.ndarray':
        array = np.array(array)

    # The computation on array
    # Do something with array
    new_array = other_func(array)
    return new_array
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simpler to use `asarray`:

```
def myfunc(arr):
    arr = np.asarray(arr)
    # The computation on array
    # Do something with array
    new_array = other_func(arr)
    return new_array
```

If `arr` is already an array, `asarray` does not make a copy, so there's no penalty to passing it through `asarray`.  Let `numpy` do the testing for you.

`numpy` functions often pass their inputs through `asarray` (or variant) just make sure the type is what they expect.

Answer (score 13):

You're quite close, but you need to call the specific class, i.e `numpy.ndarray` (here you're just comparing with a string). Also for this you have the built-in [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), too see if a given object is an instance of another:

```
def myfunc(array):
    # Check if array is not already numpy ndarray
    if not isinstance(array, np.ndarray):
        array = np.array(array)

    # The computation on array
    # Do something with array
    new_array = other_func(array)
    return new_array
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `isinstance` here.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,2,...])
isinstance(a,np.ndarray)
#True
```

---

```
def myfunc(array):
    return array if isinstance(array,np.ndarray) else np.array(array)
```

You just return `array` if it's a `np.ndarray` already else you convert `array` to `np.array`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

def myfunc(array):
    # Check if array is not already numpy ndarray
    # Not correct way, this is where I need help
    if bool(np.type(array)):
        array = np.array(array)

    else:
    print('Big array computationally expensive')
    array = np.array(array)

    # The computation on array
    # Do something with array
    new_array = other_func(array)
    return new_array
```